# Rails: TypeError can't cast Twitter::SearchResults to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, twitter

Stackoverflow community,

This is my code: (I am using twitter gem)

```
data = $twitterclient.search("#respect -rt", lang: "en", result_type: "recent")
        @twitterdata = Twitterdatum.new(:twitterjson => data)
        @twitterdata.save
```

The field twitterjson is json type not string type, I need to save json type because postgreSQL supports JSON, I know I can save it as string type and extract important information, but I want a complete json format. I need to get json format from twitter. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

When I modify the code and just render the data as plain, it works fine.

```
data = $twitterclient.search("#respect -rt", lang: "en", result_type: "recent")
render :plain => data.inspect
```

This gives me correct output.

Comment: Does `Twitterdatum.new(:twitterjson => data.to_a)` work?

Comment: wow it worked man, thanks a dozen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the response into an array:

```
Twitterdatum.new(twitterjson: data.to_a)
```